# An environment for setting \emergencystretch locally

Tags: line-breaking, environments

The following environment, copied from [this website about dealing with overfull hboxes](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-overfull), allows one to change the `\tolerance` parameter for just the paragraph(s) it encloses:

```
\newenvironment{tolerant}[1]{%
  \par\tolerance=#1\relax
}{%
  \par
}
```

Unfortunately, the website does not specify a similar environment for locally changing `\emergencystretch`. Since much of the code in the definition above (notably, the commands `\par` and `\relax`) is currently outside my understanding, I would not know how to go about making a similar environment for locally setting `\emergencystretch`--but I'm sure someone on TeX.SE would know.

How would one write an environment that changes the value of `\emergencystretch` locally (and makes sure the changes get applied)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change `\tolerance` to `\emergencystretch` and pass in a length rather than a number.

`\par` means end of paragraph and is same as a blank line. `\relax` is a primitive command which does nothing but it stops the scan for a number in case the text started with a digit.

```
\tolerance=1\relax 2 is ...
```

sets tolerance to 1 and typesets a 2 but without the `\relax` or a space then

```
 \tolerance=12 is..
```

would set it to 12 and not typeset the 2.

Answer (score 10):

TeX uses the settings for `\tolerance` or `\emergencystretch` at the end of the paragraph.
Therefore the first `\par` ends the current paragraph that is typeset with the old settings.
The `\par` in `\end{emergency}` makes sure that also the latest paragraph in the environment gets finished and typeset with the special setting of the environment.

Because `\emergencystretch` is a dimen register, LaTeX's `\setlength` can be used to set `\emergencystretch` locally:

```
\newenvironment{emergency}[1]{%
  \par
  \setlength{\emergencystretch}{#1}%
}{%
  \par
}
```

Answer (score 8):

In fact, I'd do something like the following:

```
\newenvironment{xtolerant}[2]{%
  \par
  \ifx\empty#1\empty\else\tolerance=#1\relax\fi
  \ifx\empty#2\empty\else\emergencystretch=#2\relax\fi
}{%
  \par
}
```

That way, you can decide whether to set `\tolerance` or `\emergencystretch` or both. Just leave one environment argument empty for for not setting it.

Hence,

```
\begin{xtolerant}{300}{}
  ...
\end{xtolerant}
```

will set `\tolerance` to 300 and leave `\emergencystretch` alone,

```
\begin{xtolerant}{}{2em}
  ...
\end{xtolerant}
```

will set `\emergencystretch` to 2em and leave `\tolerance` alone, and

```
\begin{xtolerant}{300}{2em}
  ...
\end{xtolerant}
```

will set `\tolerance` to 300 and set `\emergencystretch` to 2em.