# What is a "Overfull \hbox (9.89561pt too wide)"?

Tags: boxes, paragraphs, warnings

I have this warnings around, some of them seems to be solved naturally but I never really understand what do they mean.

What this means?

**Edit:** I would like to keep the question in more general terms, but in this particular case the source code related to this warning is the following:

```
\item {\bf Finalização} onde são finalizados os histogramas, eventualmente traçadas curvas de ajuste \emph{(fit)} e guardados os resultados no disco.
```

Possible duplicate: [This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51762/how-do-you-effectively-debug-overfull-hbox-warnings) solves the debug issue of this.

PS: Sorry if this question is quite newbie.

Comment: In simple words, it means you have a line of text that is too wide (9.8961pt too wide to be precise) to fit in one line, so the program tries to break it unsuccessfully, hence the warning.

Comment: But the generated pdf has this line just has expected (I will put the corresponding source in the question)

Comment: not really.  What happens is that 9.89561pt = 3.49mm, which is almost nothing for the naked (inexperienced?) eye to see.

Comment: so it is less than 10% of a single character?

Comment: @MarioS.E. 9.89...pt is, in Computer Modern @10pt, almost the width of one-and-a-half `m`s. There might be people unable to see that with the naked eye, but what these people need isn't experience, but new glasses `;)`

Comment: @NilsL good point, but since what he has is plain report text I was aiming that wasn't the case.

Comment: RSFalcon7 Have you loaded `\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}` at the beginning of the document?

Comment: @MarioS.E. I'm rewriting this document in english, so I change the `portuguese` to `english`. What is the relevance of this in the overfull hbox?

Comment: @RSFalcon7 It's important because the hyphenation of each word is given according to the language

Comment: related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35/30481

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The allowed space between two words is given by the interwordspace (`\fontdimen2\font`) and interwordstretch (`\fontdimen3\font`).  If it is not possible to set a paragraph with these lengths (with hyphenation) TeX will complain with a overfull or underfull box. Setting the `\emergencystrech` to a value greater than `0pt` it can stretch the interwordspace to a bigger value. You can set this value individually or using `\sloppy` or the environment `sloppypar`

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage[textwidth=4.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}
interwordspace: \the\fontdimen2\font \\

interwordstretch: \the\fontdimen3\font \\

emergencystretch: \the\emergencystretch\par
\blindtext

\newpage
\begin{sloppypar}
interwordspace: \the\fontdimen2\font \\

interwordstretch: \the\fontdimen3\font \\

emergencystretch: \the\emergencystretch\par
\blindtext
\end{sloppypar}

\end{document}
```

[image][image]

Comment: How to set the value of `emergencystretch`, is not mentionated on the question, but you can use `\setlength{\emergencystretch}{10pt}` from the question [An environment for setting \emergencystretch locally](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84510/an-environment-for-setting-emergencystretch-locally)

Answer (score 6):

for my case, the easiest solution that I found is to add `\begin{sloppypar}` after `\maketitle` and to add `\end{sloppypar}` at the end of my document.
It worked like charm: I don't have any text going out of the columns anymore. My document tex looks like:

```
\begin{document}
% title + keywords + abstract 
\maketitle
\begin{sloppypar}
% document body
\end{sloppypar}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please, can you put a MWE to see your solution?

Comment: i don't understand what do you mean with MWE? I had the overfull issue and I could fix it by adding sloppypar ... have you tried it? didn't work for you?

Comment: I have only asked only to put a minimal working example (MWE) of your solution starting from \documentclass to \end{document}.

Comment: `sloppy` and `sloppypar` allow large spaces between words. Using them is a last resort, not something for the whole document.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I am a beginner in the world of Latex. I just wanted to share with others what solved the issue for me... I can understand that it's not optimal, but i am going to stick with it, for the moment. I have added a MWE, with the hope it can be helpful.

Comment: Worked like a charm