# Solving overfull and underful hbox problem in table: interwordspace, interwordstretch and emergencystretch not in the given template

Tags: tables

I am getting "underfull and overfull hbox error". I found one solution uses the following:

[overfull and underfull hbox](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111948/what-is-a-overfull-hbox-9-89561pt-too-wide)

```
\begin{document}
interwordspace: \the\fontdimen2\font \\

interwordstretch: \the\fontdimen3\font \\

emergencystretch: \the\emergencystretch\par
\blindtext

\newpage
\begin{sloppypar}
interwordspace: \the\fontdimen2\font \\

interwordstretch: \the\fontdimen3\font \\

emergencystretch: \the\emergencystretch\par
\blindtext
\end{sloppypar}
```

I don’t have above tags{interwordspace, interwordstretch: and emergencystretch and begin {slopper}, please guide me.

My complete Latex code is:

```
  \documentclass[manuscript,screen]{acmart}
\usepackage{listings}
\input{solidity-highlighting.tex}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
%% \BibTeX command to typeset BibTeX logo in the docs
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \providecommand\BibTeX{{%
    \normalfont B\kern-0.5em{\scshape i\kern-0.25em b}\kern-0.8em\TeX}}}


\setcopyright{acmcopyright}
\copyrightyear{2020}
\acmYear{2020}
\acmDOI{10.1145/1122445.1122456}


\begin{document}


\title{Testing}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
First Example Table Problem
\begin{table}[]
    \caption{Contribution table, the section-wise achievement of significant work.}
    \label{tab:contributiontable}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{p{2.5cm}p{1.5cm}p{10cm}}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bf Survey Section} &
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bf Context} &
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bf The Focus of Research Papers} \\ 
      \hline
      
 \hline
 
(Section 2) 222222222222222 -- 22222222222222222222222 222222222 [23] \\

Future 41414141414141414141414141414141414141441414 41414141414: 41414141414141414141414141414141[16] \\

4344343434343434343434343434343434343434343434343434343434 343: [21] \\

      \hline 
    \end{tabular}
  \vspace{-0.1in}   
\end{table}
  \end{document}
```

The image is also attached:
[image: Image of output along with error messages]

Comment: Probably `>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{2.5cm}` gives you the desired result.

Comment: Please add some background infor on the contents of the table. Does "-- TTTTTT TTTTT TTT TTTTTT TTTTTTTTT [23000]" belong in the first column of the table or probably into the last? What ise `--` supposed to do? Do you actually want an itemize list in your last table column? Please clarify.

Comment: Probably a sketch of the desired output would be helpful as well.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have added the image again and new code with changes to prinable text

Comment: Regarding your recent update: Is "Future 41414141414141414141414141414141414141441414 41414141414: 41414141414141414141414141414141[16]" really what you want to display in your table or is it just some placeholder text for a different text? Latex does not know where to add linebreaks inside of something like `1414141414141414141414141414141414141441414`, so no wonder you are getting overfull and underfull box warnings here. What to do depends on the contents of your table: actual text or "41414141414141414141414141414141[16]"? Please clarify that.

Comment: This is not the actual texts but its of same length as the actual text. Actual text has spaces in it.