# How to force a linebreak in multiple author inline citation using biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, line-breaking

I am finishing my thesis and get ugly inline citations with multiple authors when using `biblatex`.

The issue arises especially with double last names as in the attached picture:

[image]

As you can see the name flows into the margin.
I am using `biber` and the `authoryear` style.

I tried including `\defcounter{lownamepenalty}{0}` and `\defcounter{highnamepenalty}{0}` in the preamble, but it still looks the same after a clean build.

Is there any way to make `biblatex` (or `biber`) do a linebreak earlier on in the author list, or do I have to manually make two separate multicitations? That would look ugly.

I am using `\parencite` by the way.

Comment: [This answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2780/) gives some general things you can do. (The `breakcites` package mentioned in the other answers doesn't work with `biblatex`),

Comment: Also useful: [An environment for setting \emergencystretch locally](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84510)

Comment: @AlanMunn Thank you very much. The `\begin{sloppypar}` `\end{sloppypar}` worked wonders and was just what I was looking for. Whoever named that command was a genius :). Even if this was not a new answer you can make it one if you wish, and I will accept it.

Comment: I've added an answer with a document that people can play with to see how this works.  `\sloppypar` is a kind of last resort; setting a local value for `\emergencystretch` is probably a better first approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are having is not directly related to `biblatex`, but to TeX's paragraph building system. So rather than do something to the citations themselves, it's really best to wait until the very final stages of your document and adjust individual paragraphs.

One way to do this is to use the `\sloppypar` environment, which sets various factors that affect the spacing so that normally bad paragraphs are allowed.

```
\begin{sloppypar}
  ...
\end{sloppypar}
```

Two of the factors that `sloppypar` sets are `\emergencystretch` and `\tolerance`.  See

- [What is the meaning of \fussy, \sloppy, \emergencystretch, \tolerance, \hbadness?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/241343/2693)

for an explanation of how all these work.  But the values that `\sloppypar` sets for these are quite large, so a more finegrained approach would be to use an `emergency` environment, as defined in Heiko Oberdiek's answer to this question:

- [An environment for setting \emergencystretch locally](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84510/2693)

```
\newenvironment{emergency}[1]{%
  \par
  \setlength{\emergencystretch}{#1}%
}{%
  \par
}
```

This environment sets a value for `\emergencystretch`, which might be enough to do the job. Try small values first and increase as needed.

Here's a small sample document to show how this works. I've added some bibliography items,  but as you will see, they are not directly the source of the problem. To see this, I've also added a moveable word 'foo' which will show the effects of rewording. If you play around with either the margins or the placement of the word or the settings for the `emergency` environment you can see it all in action.  The black marks show the overfull boxes.

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@article{fama-french:1997,
    Author = {Fama, Eugene F. and French, Kenneth R. },
    Journal = {Journal of Financial Economics},
    Pages = {153 - 193},
    Title = {Industry costs of equity},
    Volume = 43,
    Year = 1997}

@article{fama-french:1992,
    Author = {Fama,  Eugene F. and French, Kenneth},
    Journal = {The Journal of Finance},
    Pages = {427-465},
    Title = {The Cross-Section of Expected Stock Returns},
    Volume = 47,
    Year = 1992}

@article{fama-french:2002,
    Author = {Fama, Eugene F. and French, Kenneth R.},
    Journal = {The Journal of Finance},
    Pages = {637-659},
    Title = {The Equity Premium},
    Volume = 57,
    Year = 2002}

@book{Ribeiro-Gonsalves1992,
    Author = {Ribeiro-Gonsalves, Arturo},
    Publisher = {{MIT} Press},
    Title = {Um Livro},
    Year = {1992}}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage[width=2in]{geometry}
% change margins to see different effects

\newenvironment{emergency}[1]{%
  \par
  \setlength{\emergencystretch}{#1}%
}{%
  \par
}

\def\foo{foo }
\def\bar{foo }
% comment out these next lines individually to see different effects
% uncommenting the line *adds* the word ‘foo’ to the text.
\def\foo{\relax}
\def\bar{\relax}

\begin{document}

Some text  that will make the \foo line wrap can we make  a bad  break  realization \bar still not giving  a   break \parencite{fama-french:1992,
fama-french:1997,
fama-french:2002,
Ribeiro-Gonsalves1992}.
And some more text afterwards.

\begin{emergency}{3.45pt}
Some text  that will make the \foo line wrap can we make  a bad  break  realization \bar still not giving  a   break \parencite{fama-french:1992,fama-french:1997,
fama-french:2002,
Ribeiro-Gonsalves1992}.
And some more text afterwards.
\end{emergency}

\begin{emergency}{3.5pt}
Some text  that will make the \foo line wrap can we make  a bad  break  realization \bar still not giving  a   break \parencite{fama-french:1992,fama-french:1997,
fama-french:2002,
Ribeiro-Gonsalves1992}.
And some more text afterwards.
\end{emergency}

\begin{sloppypar}
Some text  that will make the \foo line wrap can we make  a bad  break  realization \bar still not giving  a   break \parencite{fama-french:1992,fama-french:1997,
fama-french:2002,
Ribeiro-Gonsalves1992}.
And some more text afterwards.
\end{sloppypar}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: I see the value of the `emergency` environment. But in my case the `sloppypar` produced the exact same results. I guess it was just because of the lengths of the words and the paragraphs involved.

Comment: @niclasericsson Yes it's hard to come up with  examples that would show the difference, although I'm sure they exist. The other advantage of the `\emergency` environment is that you can set the value to 0 if you reword the paragraph, whereas with `\sloppypar` you would need to remove the environment.